# Getting the value of an object that is a collection

Tags: java, collections, casting

I am using a method that returns an Object when called. That object's type is java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet . The collection holds only one value, that I need to access and feed to another method. The problem is that doing this:

```
Object o = table.getValue().toString();
```

returns the value surrounded in [ ] since it is a Collection. The other method needs to be called with Object type parameter, that should be only the value without the [ ]. I have got the thing working by removing the square brackets with regular expression, but would like to get the thing working by somehow casting the collection to an appropriate type.

Comment: `toString()` is a method. Is it a typo?

Comment: whu you need to do .toString()..Just pass as it is to the method

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me. Is this what you need? `String str = ((Set<?>)table.getValue()).toArray()[0].toString();`

Comment: What is the exact type of your `table` variable? Just asking, because you said in another comment that you don't see the collection but a row identifier...

Comment: Ahmad, passing it as a collection grants me NullPointerException when the other method tries to use it, the other method takes a parameter of Object but when calling it with the regexp'd String works okay..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the iterator:

```
String result = ((Collection) table.getValue()).iterator().next().toString();
```

will return the first value of the collections iterator. (Assuming, `table.getValue()` returns the collection)

Comment: This does it, thank you Andreas. The solution is a nice one-liner and achieves exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that this collection only contains one value you could do it like this:

```
String result = null;
Collection collection = (Collection)table.getValue();
for(Object o : collection) {
   result = o.toString();
   break;
}
```

If the collection cannot contain more than one value, you could remove the `break` after `result = o.toString();`

Hope that helps.

---

**Edit**: Modified, collection is now retrieved from table. Added cast to Collection and added break

Comment: I have no idea how this would help, since the amount of items in the table (tens of thousands) does not matter at this point and the problem with o.toString() is that it still holds the square brackets [ ] around the actual value. o is a Collection at this point, it needs to be casted to an arrayList or something like this, but I don't know how to do the conversion in a simple way (or any way for that matter). Also the return type of table.getValue() is Object, not Collection..

Comment: table.getValue() returns only the row's "identifier", for some reason that I can not affect it is of type Collection.

Comment: Teemu, in *your* code, `o` is never ever a collection but a String ;) - but it may just be a typo.

Comment: I meant if you do only Object o = table.getValue(), then you get a Collection :)

Comment: Oh ok, I was thinking table is your collection. Ok, I will modify my code example.

Comment: This still wouldn't work, since table.getValue() returns an Object, as per the first line of the question. That object's type is Collection... Still appreciate the help pushy, and this is now solved so all is well.

Comment: Added the necessary cast to Collection ;-)